# Where to find the default color scheme for python files in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor, color-scheme

Initially, I used Atom for editing my python files. I love the color scheme that IDE. I have moved on to pyCharm now. I want to set it manually to use the same color scheme as that of Atom's.

Could you tell me where I can find the default color schema data in Atom?

[image: Figure: Default Color Scheme of Python Files in Atom]

Comment: Thanks for including the picture, @suraj.

Comment: Did you g et this to work? The github doesn't include the format that pycharm wants.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is the [`atom-dark-syntax`](https://github.com/atom/atom-dark-syntax) theme. The color schemes are written in [less](/questions/tagged/less) and is available on GitHub.

If you want find the color schemes of any of your installed themes, follow these steps:

1. Go to Settings > Themes
2. Click the theme to visit its page on [atom.io](https://atom.io).
3. Click Repo.

For uninstalled themes, just go to [atom.io/themes](https://atom.io/themes), search for a theme and click Repo.